# Running a script in the -action of Register-WmiEvent

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to run a script off the back of a WMI event?

I'm trying to run the below.  The WMI event is working as shown below.

This Works:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier "FileMon" -action { Write-Host "File Dropped";  }
```

This does not:

```
Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier "FileMon" -action { Write-Host "File Dropped"; Invo
ke-Expression c:\scripts\test.ps1 }
```

Am I missing something or is there another way you're supposed to be doing this?

Edit for clarification.  1st example runs fine, 2nd doesn't appear to do anything.  No errors.

Comment: This should work - are you sure you have permissions to the script you're trying to execute? Try running the `Invoke-Expression` command within the session.

Comment: I just tried running Invoke-Expression from the terminal and it ran fine.

Comment: I agree, it should work. Did you try `Register-WmiEvent -Query $query -SourceIdentifier "FileMon" -action { Invoke-Expression c:\scripts\test.ps1 }`